# How to check if anything in firebase reference exists in javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase

So I have some code for my firebase project, and it checks when something is changed but it still runs the function even when nothing is in there and i dont want it... check below and please help!!!

```
   <script>
     firebase.database().ref('Bolos/').on('value', function(snapshot) { 
      M.toast({html: '<i class="material-icons">check_circle</i><span>Current Bolos Or Just Updated!'})
     });
   </script>
```

Basically What i wanna do is this :
When something is added, updated or deleted:

- Run That M.Toast

when reference is empty:

- Do Nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check if the `Bolos` node exists, that'd be:

```
firebase.database().ref('Bolos/').on('value', function(snapshot) { 
  if (snapshot.exists()) {
    M.toast({html: '<i class="material-icons">check_circle</i><span>Current Bolos Or Just Updated!'})
  }
});
```

If you want to detect whether a child node was added, modified or deleted, you'll want to use the relevant `child_` events:

```
function showToast() {
  M.toast({html: '<i class="material-icons">check_circle</i><span>Current Bolos Or Just Updated!'})
}

firebase.database().ref('Bolos/').on('child_added', showToast);
firebase.database().ref('Bolos/').on('child_removed', showToast);
firebase.database().ref('Bolos/').on('child_changed', showToast);
```

Comment: Thank You So Much Iv Been Looking For This For So Long, Im So Thankful!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

As per the firebase docs `on()` method read and listen to the path if anything changes.
Point to note here is that `on()` method first return the snapshot first time when the listener is attached and after that whenever any data including child changes.

The event callback is passed a snapshot containing all data at that location, including child data. If there is no data, the snapshot will return `false` when you call `exists()` and `null` when you call `val()` on it.
So you can add `if` condition to check is snapshot exists, then execute your code `else` do nothing.

Reference - https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#listen_for_value_events